# Morphia converter calling other converters

Tags: mongodb, converters, morphia

I want to convert `Optional<BigDecimal>` in morphia. I created BigDecimalConverter, and it works fine. Now I want to create OptionalConverter.

Optional can hold any object type. In my `OptionalConverter.encode` method I can extract underlying object, and I'd like to pass it to default mongo conversion. So that if there is string, I'll just get string, if there is one of my entities, I'll get encoded entity. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

There are two questions:
1. How to call other converters?
2. How to create a converter for a generic class whose type parameters are not statically known?

The first one is possible by creating the MappingMongoConveter and the custom converter together:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
        MappingMongoConverter mmc = new MappingMongoConverter(
                mongoDbFactory(), mongoMappingContext());
        mmc.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(CustomConverters
                .create(mmc)));
        return mmc;
    }
}

public class FooConverter implements Converter<Foo, DBObject> {
    private MappingMongoConverter mmc;

    public FooConverter(MappingMongoConverter mmc) {
        this.mmc = mmc;
    }

    public DBObject convert(Foo foo) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class CustomConverters {
    public static List<?> create(MappingMongoConverter mmc) {
        List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new FooConverter(mmc));
        return list;
    }
}
```

The second one is much more difficult due to type erasure. I've tried to create a converter for Scala's Map but haven't found a way. Unable to get the exact type information for the source Map when writing, or for the target Map when reading.

For very simple cases, e.g. if you don't need to handle all possible parameter types, and there is no ambiguity while reading, it may be possible though.